# Where to put the return with a filter in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a filter inside my react code. I have a warning saying that a return value is expected. I know I have to put the return before the `if` statement, but not the closing parentheses, I tried many places, and it always crying at the compilation.

```js
<div className=" grid lg:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-2 justify-center">
                {DATA.filter((val) => {
                    if (searchItem === "" || val.from.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase())) {
                        return val
                    }
                }).map((i => {
                    return(
                        <div key={i.title} className="flex justify-center">
                            <div className="max-w-xs bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg overflow-hidden my-10">
                                <div className="px-4 py-2">
                                    <h1 className="text-gray-900 font-bold text-xl uppercase"> {i.title} </h1>
                                    <p className="text-gray-600 font-semibold text-sm mt-1"> {i.description} </p>
                                </div>
                                <img className="h-56 w-full object-cover mt-2" src={i.img} alt={i.title} />
                                <div className="flex items-center justify-between px-4 py-2 bg-gray-900">
                                    <h1 className="text-gray-200 font-bold text-xl">2€</h1>
                                    {i.reserved === true ?
                                    <>
                                    <img src="./drapeau.png" alt="drapeau" className="w-7"
                                        onMouseLeave={() => {setShowMouse(false)}}
                                        onMouseEnter={() => {setShowMouse(true)}} />
                                    <Link to="/details"
                                        onClick={() => setDetails([{title: i.title, description: i.description, lots: i.lot, img: i.img, detail: i.detail }])}
                                        className="px-3 py-1 text-sm text-white bg-saf-100 uppercase font-semibold rounded">découvrir le lot</Link>
                                    <MouseTooltip
                                        className="z-50 text-saf-300 cursor-pointer"
                                        visible={showMouse}
                                        offsetY={40}
                                        >
                                        <span>Lot à expérimenter à La Réunion</span>
                                    </MouseTooltip>
                                        </>
                                    : <Link to="/details"
                                        onClick={() => setDetails([{title: i.title, description: i.description, lots: i.lot, img: i.img }])} className="px-3 py-1 text-sm uppercase text-white bg-saf-100 font-semibold rounded cursor-pointer">découvrir le lot</Link>}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }))}
            </div>
```

Comment: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should return `true` or `false`. `true` keeps the value, `false` filters it out. You aren't returning anything if the `if` condition is not met.

Comment: @BrianThompson `undefined` should convert to `false`

Comment: @TJ but if its a **warning** like the OP says, then it could easily be a warning meaning you *should* return false explicitly.

Comment: Would that really yield a warning? I would expect that to cause a true error. I don't think the question has enough information to assume they aren't returning the full JSX..

Comment: Look at the examples of incorrect code for this eslint rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return. It matches your `.filter()` code. If your warning is coming from eslint it is likely this rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just checking conditions in filter then you don't need to use `return` in filter.

You can try with following code:

```
{DATA.filter((val) => 
    searchItem === "" || val.from.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase())
}).map((i => {
  // rest of your code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to check for val.from in first place

```
searchItem === "" || ( val.from && val.from.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase()) )
```

Additionaly you can check if val.from is a string